# Getting undefined back from AWS secrets call

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I've seen this question around, but it seems nobody is having the same problem as me. I followed the AWS docs and implemented their code the way they told me to, but I keep getting undefined back?

Here's the code:

```
// Load the AWS SDK
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    region = "myRegion",
    secretName = "myARN",
    secret,
    decodedBinarySecret;

// Create a Secrets Manager client
var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
    region: region
});

// In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
// See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
// We rethrow the exception by default.

client.getSecretValue({SecretId: secretName}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'DecryptionFailureException')
            // Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
            // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            throw err;
        else if (err.code === 'InternalServiceErrorException')
            // An error occurred on the server side.
            // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            throw err;
        else if (err.code === 'InvalidParameterException')
            // You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
            // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            throw err;
        else if (err.code === 'InvalidRequestException')
            // You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
            // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            throw err;
        else if (err.code === 'ResourceNotFoundException')
            // We can't find the resource that you asked for.
            // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            throw err;
    }
    else {
        // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
        // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
        if ('SecretString' in data) {
            let secret = data.SecretString;
            secret = JSON.parse(secret);
        } else {
            let buff = Buffer.from(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
            decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString('ascii');
        }
    }
    
    // Your code goes here.
    // This is where undefined gets spit out
    console.log(decodedBinarySecret);
    console.log(secret);
});
```

There must be something that I'm missing / not doing?

Comment: There's no reason to use `var` in new JavaScript code. Always use `let` or `const`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that in the outer `else` part of your conditional statement you're re-declaring the `secret` variable which you've also declared at the very top. That secret variable gets a value but only inside the nested if body not outside. Which keeps the secret variable still undefined.

Also, according to your code either variable `secret` will have some value or `decodedBinarySecret`. One of them will be undefined.

Try not to re-declare the variable inside the body. See below code.

```
 else {
    // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
    // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary...
    if ('SecretString' in data) {
        secret = data.SecretString;
        secret = JSON.parse(secret);
    } else {
        let buff = Buffer.from(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
        decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString('ascii');
    }
}
```

Comment: I had been staring at that for a while and missed that part. I stopped re-declaring secret, but am met with same output

Comment: Then you must console log the err and data inside `client.getSecretValue` before the statement `if (err)`. So the first line should be something like `console.log(err, data)`. This will either give you the error or data. Which will be helpful in finding out what's wrong.